# facebook app invite using ionic (cordova phonegap)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, facebook-invite-friends

I would like to implement Facebook app invite into my mobile app so users can invite their friends to my app. I am using a hybrid framework called Ionic (cordova) but can't find any way to invite friends. There are Facebook plugins from ng-crodova but they do not handle app invites. Is there any plugin or simple solution to get this feature to work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to solve this problem as well.

Comment: Any luck trying my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin:

> https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Its just a [fork](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#usage) of ngCordova Facebook plugin [Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

Then you can use [appInvite](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#app-invites) like this:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.appInvite(
    {
        url: "http://example.com",
        picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
    },
    function(obj){
        if(obj) {
            if(obj.completionGesture == "cancel") {
                // user canceled, bad guy
            } else {
                // user really invited someone :)
            }
        } else {
            // user just pressed done, bad guy
        }
    },
    function(obj){
        // error
        console.log(obj);
    }
);
```

Comment: Bonna, any help you could lend would be amazing as I'm stuck on it and the example you show does not fit with the Ionic-Native plugin. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/

Comment: Sorry @rashadb I just tried my solution on ionic framework v1. I would like to start working with the new version but I still didn't take the time for it.

Comment: @Bonna, I just put FB on my tablet yesterday; new tablet. It wouldn't work because somehow an old FB was downloaded on it?!? When I updated it today it all worked just fine.